# Is there a way to include commas in CSV columns without breaking the formatting?

Tags: csv

I've got a two column CSV with a name and a number. Some people's name use commas, for example `Joe Blow, CFA.` This comma breaks the CSV format, since it's interpreted as a new column.

I've read up and the most common prescription seems to be replacing that character, or replacing the delimiter, with a new value (e.g. `this|that|the, other`).

I'd really like to keep the comma separator (I know excel supports other delimiters but other interpreters may not). I'd also like to keep the comma in the name, as `Joe Blow| CFA` looks pretty silly.

Is there a way to include commas in CSV columns without breaking the formatting, for example by escaping them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: Little hack that worked for me: open the csv file in a text editor, then paste into an excel document. Works if you can do this in big chunks.

Comment: @Jonas: Excel cannot guess, whether the same token is used as a delimiter or part of the data. Pasting from a text editor doesn't change that.

Answer (score 793, accepted):

To encode a field containing comma (`,`) or double-quote (`"`) characters, enclose the field in double-quotes:

```
field1,"field, 2",field3, ...
```

Literal double-quote characters are typically represented by a *pair* of double-quotes (`""`). For example, a field exclusively containing one double-quote character is encoded as `""""`.

For example:

```
Sheet: |Hello, World!|You "matter" to us.|

  CSV: "Hello, World!","You ""matter"" to us."
```

More examples (sheet → csv):

- `regular_value` → `regular_value`
- `Fresh, brown "eggs"` → `"Fresh, brown ""eggs"""`
- `"` → `""""`
- `","` → `""","""`
- `,,,"` → `",,,"""`
- `,"",` → `","""","`
- `"""` → `""""""""`

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Comment: This worked for me! I was exporting a js variable to CSV, and putting an extra pair of quotes around every string, helped solve the problem of "John Blow, CFA", as mentioned in the question.

Comment: What if there are both quotes and commas inside each cell?

Comment: I updated the answer with some examples - in short, commas are encapsulated in quotes (such as `","`), and quotes are escaped (e.g. `"""`)

Comment: Now THIS should be the accepted answer as it proposes a great solution that likely solves 99% of use cases.

Comment: Is there a C# library to parse csv files with quote-escaped fields?

Comment: My Excel imports the csv column with the quotes still intact. Is there a way to import the column and remove the quotes?

Comment: This is the correct answer but not that MANY csv display technologies do not honor this.

Comment: A bit late on this but wouldn't the penultimate one be ","""""","

Answer (score 67):

I found that some applications like Numbers in Mac ignore the double quote if there is space before it.

`a, "b,c"` doesn't work while `a,"b,c"` works.

Comment: Subtle parsing problems caused by invisible characters are the best.

Comment: Agree! after I copy entire content from .number file to google spreadsheet and export it as .csv, things then work fine.

Answer (score 39):

The problem with the CSV format, is there's not one spec, there are several accepted methods, with no way of distinguishing which should be used (for generate/interpret).  I discussed all the methods to escape characters (newlines in that case, but same basic premise) in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025831/creating-carriage-returns-in-csv-cell-via-php/4026152#4026152).  Basically it comes down to using a CSV generation/escaping process for the intended users, and hoping the rest don't mind.

[Reference spec document](http://www.csvreader.com/csv_format.php).

Comment: RFC 4180, Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files, https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt; one further 'official' specification.

Comment: Including the most widely-accepted approach would make this a great answer. As it stands, the answer by @Ryan wins.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to make that you said, you can use quotes. Something like this

```
$name = "Joe Blow, CFA.";
$arr[] = "\"".$name."\"";
```

so now, you can use comma in your name variable.

Comment: Thanks Cloud for your tip, that did it:

`$whatever = "\"".$name."\"";`

Comment: Thanks for you solution.

Answer (score 14):

You need to quote that values.
[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210401084212/http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm) is a more detailed spec.

Comment: There are multiple specs, Excel uses quotes around the entry, Linux uses the backslash character.  Unfortunately, you need to escape for your intended audience/target system.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the points in other answers: one thing to note if you are using quotes in Excel is the placement of your spaces. If you have a line of code like this:

```
print '%s, "%s", "%s", "%s"' % (value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4)
```

Excel will treat the initial quote as a literal quote instead of using it to escape commas. Your code will need to change to

```
print '%s,"%s","%s","%s"' % (value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4)
```

It was this subtlety that brought me here.

Answer (score 10):

CSV files can actually be formatted using different delimiters, comma is just the default.

You can use the `sep` flag to specify the delimiter you want for your CSV file.

Just add the line `sep=;` as the very first line in your CSV file, that is if you want your delimiter to be semi-colon. You can change it to any other character.

[image: Example]

Comment: Nice tip, but isn't this Excel specific?

Answer (score 8):

You can use Template literals (Template strings)

e.g -

```
`"${item}"`
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: This just stringifies and wraps `item` in double quotes but using template literals has little to do with it, and while this works it doesn't explain the underlying issue or the solution.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a perfect solution, but you can just replace all uses of commas with `‚` or a lower quote.  It looks very very similar to a comma and will visually serve the same purpose.  No quotes are required

in JS this would be

```
stringVal.replaceAll(',', '‚')
```

You will need to be super careful of cases where you need to directly compare that data though

Comment: I feel like this is a bad idea - live how sometimes a bug is caused by a zero-width character.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your language, there may be a to_json method available. That will escape many things that break CSVs.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and quoting the `,` did not help. Eventually, I replaced the `,` with `+`, finished the processing, saved the output into an outfile and replaced the `+` with `,`. This may seem ugly but it worked for me.

Comment: And what would you have done if the data contained "+" characters?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, that is a challenge. But in my case, I am sure that `+` does not exist in my data at all. Thanks for you kind comment.

Comment: The simple and robust way is to enclose the strings in double-quotes and escape double-quotes within strings by using two of them like `""`. This is the normal way of doing it.

Comment: If it isn't working, check that you are not generating spaces alongside your delimiting commas:
"Frog","yellow, green" will work
"Frog", "yellow, green" will not

Comment: Personally I found @AndrewMorton second comment here actually helped me understand what do better than accepted answer. Step 1 - escape double quotes in the data fields, eg in Python: `field = field.replace('"', '""')` Step 2 - after Step 1, enclose field itself in double quotes eg `field = '"' + field + '"'` - then you're iron-cast I think.

Answer (score 2):

May not be what is needed here but it's a very old question and the answer may help others.  A tip I find useful with importing into Excel with a different separator is to open the file in a text editor and add a first line like:

sep=|

where | is the separator you wish Excel to use.
Alternatively you can change the default separator in Windows but a bit long-winded:

Control Panel>Clock & region>Region>Formats>Additional>Numbers>List separator [change from comma to your preferred alternative].  That means Excel will also default to exporting CSVs using the chosen separator.

Answer (score 1):

You could encode your values, for example in PHP base64_encode($str) / base64_decode($str)

IMO this is simpler than doubling up quotes, etc.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

The encoded values will never contain a comma so every comma in your CSV will be a separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Text_Qualifier` field in your Flat file connection manager to as `"`. This should wrap your data in *quotes* and only separate by commas which are outside the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

First, if item value has double quote character ("), replace with 2 double quote character ("")

```
item = item.ToString().Replace("""", """""")
```

Finally, wrap item value:

ON LEFT: With double quote character (")

ON RIGHT: With double quote character (") and comma character (,)

```
csv += """" & item.ToString() & ""","
```

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes not worked for me, it worked for me `\"`. If you want to place a double quotes as example you can set `\"\"`.

You can build formulas, as example:

```
fprintf(strout, "\"=if(C3=1,\"\"\"\",B3)\"\n");
```

will write in csv:

> =IF(C3=1,"",B3)

Answer (score 0):

A C# method for escaping delimiter characters and quotes in column text. It should be all you need to ensure your csv is not mangled.

```
private string EscapeDelimiter(string field)
    {
        if (field.Contains(yourEscapeCharacter))
        {
            field = field.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
            field = $"\"{field}\"";
        }

        return field;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tab-separated (`tsv`) files are superior to `csv` and are supported and understood by Excel and other applications. It is highly puzzling that csv files are still in use. Wherever possible use `tsv`. Commas, double quotes and semi-colons all tend to occur in text (leading to a quagmire of non-standardised encoding conventions), `<TAB>` characters very much not so. Although not an answer to the question itself, it is worthwhile pointing out for those coming here for whom escaping from `csv` files is still an option.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the quotation to the string like this  `data = '"'+data+'"'` this worked for me on ReactJS.