# How to insert comma text into CSV in Java

Tags: java, android, excel, csv

I have 3 fields in my CSV,

```
Name | Age | Comment
----------------------
Kiran   25    testing, the space
Madhu   29    Wow, how beautiful it is, lets go
```

I'm facing problem in inserting comma separated comment in to CSV.

If i try to insert the comma separated text into CSV, the content will be moved to different column, is there way to escape the comma separated text in Java

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617935/is-there-a-way-to-include-commas-in-csv-columns-without-breaking-the-formatting)

The consensus seems to be that commas need to be enclosed in quotes to not start a new column -- however the quotes themselves might also have to be escaped.