# c# Read/ Write CSV - excluding Comma in field Value

Tags: c#, csv

Im trying to read a csv file and extract certain columns from the file and write them to a new file. Its all fine apart from when there is a comma in one of fields and its throwing everything thing out.
e.g sample CSV

1   Mr  John    Smith   123 fake street,    Fake Road, (commas causing issue)

My current code is

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(File1)
                 .Select(line => {
                     var col = line.Split(',');
                     return string.Join(",", col[0], col[1], col[2], col[3], col[4], col[5], col[6], col[7], col[8],
                          col[10]
                          , col[11], col[12], col[13], col[14], col[15], col[17], col[24], col[25], col[26]
                          , col[28], col[29], col[30], col[31], col[32], col[34], col[35], col[36], col[37]
                          , col[38], col[39], col[40], col[41], col[42], col[43], col[57], col[58], col[59]
                          , col[60], col[62], col[63]);
                 }).ToList();
            File.WriteAllLines(File1, lines);
```

Any quick ideas to fix the comma issue would be welcome.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use diedcated library - no need for reinventing the wheel. See CsvHelper.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617935/is-there-a-way-to-include-commas-in-csv-columns-without-breaking-the-formatting

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/textfieldparser

Comment: Cheers guys, sound for the quick response :)

Comment: So this question is significantly at risk of becoming a "recommend me a CSV parser". Closing as a dupe.