# how to split my regular expression using index value

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I need to split my regular expression like "hey,my,name,"john,boy",age,male".
when i try to split using (,) its split into hey,my,name,john,boy,age,male.
but i need the output as

hey
my
name
john,boy
age
male

```
 line="hey,my,name,"john,boy",age,male";
    String[] line1 = line.split(",")
           String slNo = line1[0];
           String customerId = line1[1];
           String customerCategory = line1[2];
```

Output:hey,my,name,john,boy,age,male

Comment: `line`is not valid

Comment: looks like a csv parser might be a better option. As these quotes [are designed for escaping a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617935/is-there-a-way-to-include-commas-in-csv-columns-without-breaking-the-formatting)

Comment: You aren't splitting a regular expression here. You are splitting a line of data. There is no regular expression here at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than split, it will be much easier to use `find` using this regex to get your desired strings from group1 and if group1 is null then just the whole match,

```
"([^"]+)"|[^,]+
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OSsmI5/2)**

Check this Java code,

```
String s = "hey,my,name,\"john,boy\",age,male";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"|[^,]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

while (m.find()) {
    words.add(m.group(1) == null ? m.group() : m.group(1)); // store all the found words in this ArrayList
}

String[] line1 = words.toArray(new String[words.size()]);
String slNo = line1[0];
String customerId = line1[1];
String customerCategory = line1[2];

words.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints the strings as you wanted,

```
hey
my
name
john,boy
age
male
```

Comment: thanks and i need to assign splitted values into another individuale variables?

Comment: @JayaramRockstar: You can capture all the values in an ArrayList or array and then access them the way you want. Updated my answer where all the found words are stored in a `List` from where you can use the way you tried in your code in your post.

Comment: I've also added your codes in your post to show how you can use the captured values the way you wanted. Let me know if you face any issues.