# Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm trying to parse a CSV file with CSVReader. There are around 50K records in the file. Few records have comma inside the quoted string. When the parser encounters such lines, am getting the below exception

```
java.io.IOException: Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text: 2E,C1,Sample CTitle,Name1; Name2; Name3,Name1@abc.in; Name2@abc.in; Name3@abc.in,2017-10-31
    at com.opencsv.CSVReader.readNext(CSVReader.java:353) ~[opencsv-4.5.jar:na]
    at com.opencsv.CSVReader.readAll(CSVReader.java:320) ~[opencsv-4.5.jar:na]
```

Line in CSV file:

"105144","Sample title, 2E","C1","Sample CTitle","Name1; Name2; Name3","Name1@abc.in; Name2@abc.in; Name3@abc.in","2017-10-31".

If I have only this line and not more records in CSV file, the parser works fine with this record.

Comment: Enclose the field in quotes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617935/is-there-a-way-to-include-commas-in-csv-columns-without-breaking-the-formatting