# How to remove comma in a string while writing into csv file with comma separator in java

Tags: java, string, opencsv

I am working on a java project. I have to retain a comma separator from my parsed string  ","  and still should be able to write into csv file. currently my csv file values are separated with comma (",") in it . because of this , if I have comma in a string  its divided into two string on csv

ex:

input string : "Animal","Stand","Earth","owner,jeff"

my current output : (which is incorrect )

[image]

Expected output :

[image]

I have the logic in place for writing things into csv , I just need the string to be manipulated in a such way it should in corporate the ",". how to achieve this ?

here is my code:

```js
private static void Addrow(String Animals, String Posture, String planet,String owner) throws IOException {
        String csv_write = csv_file_to_write;
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv_write , true));

            String [] record = (Animals+","+Posture+","+planet+","+owner).split(",");

        writer.writeNext(record);

        writer.close();

    }
```

Comment: Add the code that you have tried.

Comment: @javaDev I have updated my code , plz refer

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [Is there a way to include commas in CSV columns without breaking the formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4617935/7722745)

Comment: @asn21 i have read that post there they talk about enclosing the string with " " 
but in my case entire string looks something like this 

`"Animal","'Stand'","Earth","Owner","Jeff" ` how to enclose this with " "?

Comment: I was able to remove the quotes by CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER but now i am not able to add quotes around the exact string i want

Answer (score 1):

One way to tackle that would be to split it at `\",\"` and for the first entry remove the `"` at the beginning and for the last entry remove the `"` at the end. You will then be left with the list of strings `Animal`, `Stand`, `Earth`, `Owner,Jeff` and so on...