# Comma within a field of csv file. Exporting the data on regular basis

Tags: command-line, export, command-line-interface, dataloader

We will be exporting the data through command line data loader
I have a CSV file - it has many values with comma as a part of them. The commas within the fields will mislead and making it seem like the row has more columns than previously.

Name,Amount,Address

Me,20,000,My Home,India

you,23,300,Your Home,Where

What are my options here as it will be automated process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to include commas in CSV columns without breaking the formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617935/is-there-a-way-to-include-commas-in-csv-columns-without-breaking-the-formatting)

Comment: No. My process is automated. @Jacob K

Comment: Unless you can modify the list separator setting on every machine you intend to open the file from commas, part of your automated process must escape the values that include commas with quotation marks.