# Add data in double quotes and with comma at the end

Tags: python, pandas, excel, csv, google-colaboratory

I want to add the csv data in double quotes and want comma at the end. Any idea on how we can achieve that? Would like to have solution which I can run in Microsoft excel or in Google colab. Apologies if the question is not in correct format. English is not my first language and I am a new programmer.

Current data-

[image]

Expected output-

[image]

Comment: There already thread on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617935/is-there-a-way-to-include-commas-in-csv-columns-without-breaking-the-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, I would just do this:

```
=""""&A1&","""
```

But I have the comma misplaced:

```
=""""&A1&""","
```

Like so:

[image]

The you can copy & paste.special values.